# How do I repeat the small row next to the big rows in a CSV file? (VLOOKUP function, maybe?)

Tags: java, regex, excel, csv

Can I do that with Excel or Regex?

I have a small row (of two columns), followed by multiple rows of 7 columns each. I don't know the exact contents of each cell and I don't know how many large rows are following each small rows.

What I want is to move the small rows next the ALL of the following large rows.

I want this:

```
title1, title2
bla, wla, bla, tra, bla, vla, bla
bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
bla, wa, sla, na, wla, kla, pla
title3, title4
bla, wa, sla, na, wla, kla, pla
bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
bla, wla, bla, tra, bla, vla, bla
bla, wla, bla, tra, bla, vla, bla
bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
title5, title6
bla, wla, bla, tra, bla, vla, bla
bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
title7, title8
bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
...
...
```

To become this:

```
title1, title2, bla, wla, bla, tra, bla, vla, bla
title1, title2, bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
title1, title2, bla, wa, sla, na, wla, kla, pla
title3, title4, bla, wa, sla, na, wla, kla, pla
title3, title4, bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
title3, title4, bla, wla, bla, tra, bla, vla, bla
title3, title4, bla, wla, bla, tra, bla, vla, bla
title3, title4, bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
title5, title6, bla, wla, bla, tra, bla, vla, bla
title5, title6, bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
title7, title8, bla, wa, bla, bla, sla, bla, pla
...
...
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Are you limited to using Excel alone?  Handling this in Java would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, my knowledge of Java is very limited. How would you do it in Java?

Comment: You just need a rudimentary parser.  If a line has 2 entries, then cache it and prefix each subsequent line _not_ having two entries with those cached two CSV entries.

Comment: @Emilio is there a programming language you are familiar with? I think Tims approach by far isn't java only.

Comment: @SebastianProske mostly Javascript

Comment: Do you have Notepad++?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes!

Comment: I played around regex in Notepad++ but I didn't come up with anything.  The thing is, the number of rows to rewrite after the first one is variable.  Regex probably isn't the best tool here, instead use a parser.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: In case someone (possibly I) wants to give you code, is the sample file you showed the actual format?  This is to avoid someone wasting time solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes! Except each element (cell) is within double quotes, as the CSV standard allows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks a lot!

Comment: I gave you an answer, tested and working, below.  If you don't know enough about Java or programming to use it, then you have another problem to deal with.

Comment: @Emilio Did  you mean Java or Javascript? Those languages are different to each other.

Comment: @reporter I prefer Javascript. They prefer Java. I will remove the Javascript tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Java code which achieves what you are trying to do.  It reads in the input file you gave in your question above, and then using rudimentary parsing logic, writes out the format you want.  The crux of the logic is the line which checks the number of commas in the current line.  If it sees only a single comma, then it caches that line, which will be used in subsequent lines *not* having a single comma as a prefix to those lines.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    File in = new File("C:\\path\\to\\input.txt");
    File out = new File("C:\\path\\to\\output.txt");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out));
        String header = "";

        do {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null) break;
            int numCommas = line.length() - line.replace(",", "").length();
            if (numCommas == 1) {
                header = line;
            }
            else {
                bw.write(header + ", " + line);
                bw.newLine();
            }
        } while (true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) br.close();
            if (bw != null) bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't know enough Java to make use of this, then you'll need to figure that out yourself somehow.  This is as bare bones as a Java program can get.

This code was tested locally on IntelliJ and it appears to be working.

Comment: Thanks 1000 times!

Comment: I am just waiting to see if someone can do it with Excel. If not, I will mark yours as best. :)

Comment: This can probably be done with VBA, or even Excel macros, but I doubt it is possible with base Excel.  Let's see what happens next.

Comment: Maybe something can be done with the VLOOKUP function ( https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1897-excel-repeat-cell-value-x-times.html ) which basically does magic, but I'm not sure at all.